# could WDYT? acronym be listed as common acronym?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comment, homework

Very often I notice that homework questions are accompanied by a very low OP effort in trying to figure out by him/herself what the possible answer might be.
When I see such questions (which usually have quite trivial answers) I tend to comment "What Did You Try?" to try to get them thinking.

Now, could the acronym "WDYT?" be listed in the common acronyms, so we could use it in comments? Do you think it could be useful? I would see it as a signal to the OP that this community is somehow organized in not directly answering trivial homework questions.

Comment: [Here are some comment templates that you can use.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates)

Comment: thanks! I'll use those then.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, such acronyms should never be used in comments directed at the OP.

If you don't have the time to write a **helpful** comment, leave commenting to someone who does.

Comment: ok but what would helpful mean if the OP does not show any effort and the question is clearly copy-pasted from some assignment?

Comment: @marcotrevi: Just because the OP shows no effort is no reason to compound the situation with further lack of effort. We want comments and answers to improve the site, not turn it into a battle waged between people who couldn't care less.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 17):

Many such OP's are new to the site. They would not know what that acronym means. This would just lead to confusion.